# Filter and save back HAR Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, har

**Background**

I am working on a tool that would let users upload HAR files and keep replaying them over and over and gather analytics, like average speed over time, service availability etc. I already have core code in place here,  that takes Har files, and spawns up processes that replay them and collect analytics in a flat file database.

https://github.com/shaunakv1/node-chrome-har-replay

Next, I am working on building a web front-end that will let users upload a HAR file, visualize them, very similar to some of these tools here.

http://ericduran.github.io/chromeHAR/

http://rafacesar.github.io/simplehar/

http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/

Now, after visualizing them, feature that I am looking for is add something like a angular filter, that will let users enter regex strings, and filter the URLs they are interested in , and then save back the HAR file to the server.

Tool will then keep replaying this saved HAR and generate performance analytics, dashboards and all the good stuff.

**Finally the question:**

Know any tools/libraries out there that will let me filter those HAR files in the browser and save back? None of the examples i posted , do the filtering and saving part.

I can definitely start writing one myself, but looking for suggestions to see if one already exists. I am working in nodejs, so node libraries would be ideal, but not necessary. Even applications that let me filter are fine. Chrome has an excellent filter, but unfortunately does not save back filtered HAR.The most ideal would be an opensource tool, just like ones above that does filtering on web and saves the HAR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no direct way to do that. This is how I have filtered the requests and saved it back to a `har` file.

[Create a har file with xhr request only in chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325758/create-a-har-file-with-xhr-request-only-in-chrome-dev-tools)