# Create a har file with xhr request only in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, har

Is there a way to create a `har` file with `xhr` request only in chrome dev tools?

Even though I can filter the requests in dev tools, when I save it as a har file, it contains all the requests.

If the dev devtools doesn't support that, is there a alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like there is no direct way to filter the requests. What I did was, creating the `har` file with all the requests and filter that file, then save it again after removing unwanted requests.

There is a entry called `entries` in the content inside `har` file. It contains all the requests we have sent in an array. I got the `har` file content and filtered it using `JSONPath` expressions.

[About JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2), [JSONPAth evaluator](https://jsonpath.com/)

Expression to filter `application/json` types : `$..entries[?(@.response.content.mimeType == "application/json")]`

After that I have replaced the entries array with the one I have filtered in the `har` file and saved it again. This way you can get a `har` file with filtered requests. Same way you can filter `XHR` or any other types using the relevant `JSONPath` expression

Comment: Could you please share code, how can I extract XHR call only from .har file

Comment: Try this, `$..entries[?(@._resourceType == "xhr")]`

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this same issue while doing some research for mocking network calls in playwright. It does provide ability to record only the call you are interested in. Here is the link:
https://playwright.dev/docs/network#recording-har-with-cli