# Can I export HAR file from Chrome Dev tools, which contains only the filtered requests from Network tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, har

In Chrome Dev tools/Network tab I have filtered the requests using filter like "-.json -.png -.woff2".
I want to export the remaining requests (those which are visible on the screen).
However when I use "Export HAR..." icon, in the output HAR file I still get all the requests including the hidden.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

This is currently not possible in Chrome DevTools:

> DevTools saves all requests that have occurred since you opened DevTools to the HAR file. There is no way to filter requests, or to save just a single request.

Ref. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#save-as-har

However, since a HAR file is just a JSON, you can use something like jq to extract the requests you are interested in.

Let's say that you exported a HAR file from a Wikipedia page and called it `wiki.har`. Here is how you can create a HAR file containing only the requests for the images on that page:

```
cat wiki.har | jq 'del(.log.entries)' > wiki-with-no-entries.json
cat wiki.har | jq '.log.entries | map(select(._resourceType == "image"))' > image-entries.json
cat wiki-with-no-entries.json | jq '.log += {"entries": $myEntries}' --argfile myEntries image-entries.json > wiki-with-image-entries.json
```

Note 1: `_resourceType` can be `document`, `image`, `font`, `stylesheet`, `script`, `other` (maybe more? I could not find any documentation about this).

Note 2: the [jq documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) recommends using `--slurpfile` instead of `--argfile`. However, `--slurpfile` here would create `entries:[[]]`, while `--argfile` creates `entries:[]` (which is what you need). This is probably just me not knowing too much jq though...

See also:

- [Create a har file with xhr request only in chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325758/create-a-har-file-with-xhr-request-only-in-chrome-dev-tools)

Answer (score 1):

You could give webQsee (https://webqsee.com) a try. It allows you to export filtered events. HAR format is one option. Additional options are Excel (also contains console outputs) and "Behavior Reports". They combine network and console output with the screen video.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use fiddler classic to record, filter and export the requests to har.

You can filter them as you like on the "Filters" tab on the right and then go to Files > Export Sessions > All Sessions > Select HTTP Archive 2.0

Bam, filtered requests into .har.

PS: it exports into utf-8-sig format, it can be converted using Notepad++